# Capture a string which contains '(' and ')' using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex, regex-group

I would like to capture the whole string which appears after 'Value - ' till 'TestRun' in a group capture using the below expression but it does not consider the literal ')'. How to capture the string till 'TestRun'?

Regular expression:

```
Value - ([\\\w-:_.*\(\)]+)\s
```

Text:

```
Value - F:\TEMP\Radio\5\M\Try_Remove\6( alt )\TestRun End
```

Comment: Try `Value - (.*\\TestRun)\s` https://regex101.com/r/3sFJhj/1

Comment: What means "-" in your regexp? or you are asking for solution only?

Comment: Selvin - Yes. I am trying to figure out how to capture (alt) along with the whole string.Within the group capture ' - ' meant to capture ' - ' in the input text.

Comment: [edit] your question and post a sample input string as well as the output you wish to obtain from that string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern that you tried does not match a space and will stop matching after the opening parenthesis.

You could for example match what is allowed in the character class without the parenthesis or match from an opening will closing parenthesis using a non capturing group and a quantifier.

```
Value - ([\\\w:_.*-]+(?:\([^()]*\)[\\\w:_.*-]*)*)\s
```

**Explanation**

- `Value -`  Match literally
- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[\\\w:_.*-]+` Match 1+ times any of the listed
  - `(?:` Non capture group

    - `\([^()]*\)[\\\w:_.*-]*` Match from `(`..`)` and 0+ times any of the listed
  - `)*` Close group and repeat 0+ times
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s` Match a whitespace char

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Value+-+%28%5b%5c%5c%5cw%3a_.*-%5d%2b%28%3f%3a%5c%28%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%5b%5c%5c%5cw%3a_.*-%5d*%29*%29%5cs&i=Value+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%28+alt+%29%5cTestRun+End%0d%0aValue+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%5cTestRun+End%0d%0aValue+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%28) (Click the Table tab to see the group value)

A more broad pattern is to match until the last occurrence of the `/` and then match a following non whitespace chars

```
Value - (.*\\\S+)\s
```

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=Value+-+%28.*%5c%5c%5cS%2b%29%5cs&i=Value+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%28+alt+%29%5cTestRun+End%0d%0aValue+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%5cTestRun+End%0d%0aValue+-+F%3a%5cTEMP%5cRadio%5c5%5cM%5cTry_Remove%5c6%28)